# Understanding how calling a protected method belonging to one object works under a different object

Tags: php, oop

Can anyone explain why the below code works, at least for the protected method call:

```
<?php
class Component
{
    public function callMethod($obj, $method)
    {
        return $obj->$method();
    }
}

class Component1 extends Component
{
    public function aPublicMethod()
    {
        return 'called aPublicMethod()';
    }

    protected function aProtectedMethod()
    {
        return 'called aProtectedMethod()';
    }

    private function aPrivateMethod()
    {
        return 'called aPrivateMethod()';
    }
}

class Component2 extends Component
{}

$component1 = new Component1();
$component2 = new Component2();

echo $component2->callMethod($component1, 'aPublicMethod'); // works
echo $component2->callMethod($component1, 'aProtectedMethod'); // works
echo $component2->callMethod($component1, 'aPrivateMethod'); // returns an error because the private method is not accessible
```

Is it simply because both objects extend from the same parent class, and this contextual information allows Component2 to access Component1's protected methods (and properties)? This was just something I came across with a framework that follows a similar style and was trying to figure out why the second object was still able to access a protected method from another object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very good question.

As far as I can tell, its because `$component1->aProtectedMethod();` is being called from within a scope that sits within the the inheritance chain (`Component1` is a `Component` polymorphically, where the method is invoked). Which satisfies the requirements for accessing `protected` scope.

Having access to `public` scope speaks for itself. So this works anyway.

The error raised by calling `$component1->aPrivateMethod();` from outside the class that declares it (outside `private` scope), also behaves as expected. Only `Component1` instances can call `aPrivateMethod` from withing their encapsulated runtime.

Comment: Makes sense. Did a bit of reading and I think this falls under this section of documentation of the PHP docs

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visibility-other-objects